# USDC sent on ARB to an ETH gnosis safe. Need to recover funds form gnosis-safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

Replayed the safe according to the loom video instructions. However the funds dont show in the UI and is saying it needs to be done through CLI.
I have no exp with command line and would appreciate help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you deployed the safe to the correct address? Do the tokens appear in arbiscan?

In any case, you can do it from the webpage. Make a new general transaction (should be called "Contract interaction"). Now put the following info:

- `To address`: the token address
- `ABI`: copy this:

```
[
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "name": "_value",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "transfer",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
```

- `_to (address)`: where to transfer the tokens to
- `_value (uint256)`: the amount of tokens to transfer. You need to write it in natural units. So to transfer 100 USDC you need to write `100000000` (USDC has 6 decimals). You can use arbiscan to check the amount in your safe.

Comment: Thanks sir, that worked!